# PHP Cleaning up nested arrays with unknown structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, recursiveiterator

Let's assume I have an array like so:

```
[1=>[1=>2,2=>"something"],2=>[1,2],3=>"hello"]
```

The array has a "unorganized" structure with subarrays other values.

I want to run a `htmlentities` function on each value to make sure nothing bad is inside the values.

I've been reading up on `RecursiveIteratorIterator` but I cannot find an example of how to use it to apply a **function** to each value in a quite random nested multidimensional array. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply make use of [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$value) {
  $value = htmlentities($value);
});
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QmRJr

Comment: Also, can I just write array_walk_recursive($input,'htmlentities') ?

Comment: @MatthewSemik Unfortunately not, because the return value of the callback doesn't matter in that case (contrary to `array_map` for instance). You have to change the value itself, hence the `&` before the parameter.